# Writing to JSON Database if ID hasn't been defined yet

Tags: javascript

I want to have a JSON file that looks like that:

```
{
    "3091015": {
        "array": [
            "value 1",
            "value 2",
            ...
        ]
    },
    "9096539": {
        "array": [
            "value 1",
            "value 2",
            ...
        ]
    },
    ...
}
```

And what I want to do is to write or append to this file if new value needs to be added to one of the existing ID's array or if a new ID with its array and first value needs to be added. So it will work as a Database. I want to use JSON for this to be able to easily modify the content of that file manually, also it will be never bigger than 1 or 2 MB. Here is some code that actually works but only if a given ID and it's array are already defined in JSON file:

```
fs.readFile("./db.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    let json = JSON.parse(data);
    if (!json) {
      json[identificator] = {};
    }
    if (!json[identificator].array) {
      json = json[identificator] = {
        array: []
      };
    }
    let array = json[identificator].array;
    if (array.includes(value)) return;
    array.push(value);
    fs.writeFile("./db.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditionals are wrong. You need to test whether `json[identificator]` exists, not whether `json` exists.

Also, `json = json[identificator] = ...` is wrong, since it replaces `json` with just one entry.

```
fs.readFile("./db.json", "utf8", (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    throw err;
  } else {
    let json = data ? JSON.parse(data) : {};
    if (!json[identificator]) {
      json[identificator] = {
        array: []
      };
    }
    let array = json[identificator].array;
    if (array.includes(value)) return;
    array.push(value);
    fs.writeFile("./db.json", JSON.stringify(json, null, 4), err => {
      if (err) throw err;
    });
  }
});
```